# How to decide whether to use return or plain variable manipulation inside functions?

Tags: python-3.x, function, oop, return

I know that return is like throwing out a value at the end of an operation and that it actually stops the iteration or the function in which it's residing. I am having this very simple piece of code where classmethods & class variables are used.

```
class Person:
    number_of_people = 0
    def __init__(self, name):
        #Person.number_of_people +=1
        Person.add_person()
    @classmethod
    def get_person_count(cls):
        return cls.number_of_people
    @classmethod
    def add_person(cls):
        # return cls.number_of_people+1 <-- this does not work. Output is 0 and 0. Why?
        cls.number_of_people += 1 #<-- this works
P1 = Person("Rups")
print(P1.get_person_count())
P2 = Person("RG")
print(P2.get_person_count())
```

As I have commented on the lines, why is my method giving output 0 both times and not the expected output(1 & 2), which is achieved using plan variable modification? Either way, I thought I should be able to use the value given out by add_person method in the **init** method, since there is no looping involved.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a value does not mean it is modifying a variable. It just means that something can use what is returned. The difference is that `cls.number_of_people += 1` changes `number_of_people` to it's value + 1 (due to the = sign), while `return cls.number_of_people+1` takes `number_of_people` + 1 and "throws" it for something else to use.

What this means is that if add_person returns a value, anytime you call add_person(), there is a value that can be used.

```
    # {...}
    def add_person(cls):
        return cls.number_of_people + 1

P1 = Person("Rups")
print(P1.add_person()) # prints 1 (number_of_people which is 0, then add 1)
print(P1.add_person()) # still prints 1
```